# Why does not insert these values in database using Ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, mysqli

I used tutorialspoint to guide me to insert the values from input text into the db, but unfortunately, it will not insert to the database. Is this correct implementation for AJAX?

### Here's my index.php

```
<html>
<body>

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
<!-- 
//Browser Support Code
function ajaxFunction(){
   var ajaxRequest;  // The variable that makes Ajax possible!
   try{

      // Opera 8.0+, Firefox, Safari
      ajaxRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
   }catch (e){

      // Internet Explorer Browsers
      try{
         ajaxRequest = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
      }catch (e) {

         try{
            ajaxRequest = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
         }catch (e){

            // Something went wrong
            alert("Your browser broke!");
            return false;
         }
      }
   }

   // Create a function that will receive data
   // sent from the server and will update
   // div section in the same page.
   ajaxRequest.onreadystatechange = function(){

      if(ajaxRequest.readyState == 4){
         var ajaxDisplay = document.getElementById('ajaxDiv');
         ajaxDisplay.innerHTML = ajaxRequest.responseText;
      }
   }


   // Now get the value from user and pass it to
   // server script.
   var fname = document.getElementById('fname').value;
   var lname = document.getElementById('lname').value;
   var gen = document.getElementById('gen').value;
  // var queryString = "?age=" + age ;

    queryString +=  "&fname=" + fname + "&lname=" + lname+ "&gen=" + gen;
   ajaxRequest.open("GET", "ajax.php" + queryString, true);
   ajaxRequest.send(null); 
}
//-->
</script>

<form name='myForm'>

   First Name: <input type='text' id='fname' /> <br />
   Last Name: <input type='text' id='lname' /> <br />
   Sex: 
   <select id='gen'>
      <option value="m">m</option>
      <option value="f">f</option>
   </select>
   <input type='button' onclick='ajaxFunction()' value='Query MySQL'/>

</form>
<div id='ajaxDiv'>Your result will display here</div>
</body>
</html>
```

### ajax.php

```
<?php
$dbhost = "localhost";
$dbuser = "root";
$dbpass = "";
$dbname = "my_db";


$con =  new mysqli($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass,$dbname);


$query="INSERT INTO table1 (fname, lname, gender)
VALUES
('$_GET[fname]','$_GET[lname]','$_GET[gen]')";

$qry_result = $con->query($query);


?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change your code  to the bellow

```
var queryString;

queryString =  "fname=" + fname + "&lname=" + lname+ "&gen=" + gen;

ajaxRequest.open("GET", "ajax.php?" + queryString, true);
```

and make sure ajax.php is in the same folder as index.php

Comment: Sir, It says, OBJECT NOT FOUND. :?

Comment: you have not declared the javascript variable... define it as : var queryString  and then attach the values to send it

Comment: Sir, I did, I tried to declare it but same as result

Comment: are you using jquery ? then I can help you with the jquery ajax answer which would be working 100%

Comment: Thanks. but Jquery and Ajax are not the same right? I try to google the JQuery, it works, but in Ajax, it seemed do not work. But thanks.

Comment: the code above which you are using is pure ajax... but if you use jquery ajax then the code is different... and it has its own method of sending data... much more simple...

Comment: i am sure this link would be helpful for you.. http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_ajax_post

Comment: Thanks. but still does not answer my question.

Comment: This one?    var queryString;

        queryString =  "fname=" + fname + "&lname=" + lname+ "&gen=" + gen;

Comment: yes after that the problem was here.... : ajaxRequest.open("GET", "ajax.php?" + queryString, true);

Answer (score 1):

Try this in ajax.php:

```
$fname=$_GET['fname'];
$lname=$_GET['lname'];
$gen=$_GET['gen'];

$query="INSERT INTO table1 ('fname', 'lname', 'gender')
        VALUES('$fname','$lname','$gen')";
```

Answer (score 0):

Declare Form method="POST"

and

```
$query="INSERT INTO table1 (fname, lname, gender) VALUES
('".$_POST['fname']."','".$_POST['lname']."','".$_POST['gen']."')";
```